# How does the Linux shell get the return code value for $? variable?

Tags: shell, exit-code, waitpid

Does the Linux shell do a fork/exec and then waitpid() to get the return code to populate the $? variable, each time it executes something?

Comment: How else would it do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it does.

You can see this for yourself, if you are interested, by running the shell under `strace` (a tool that intercepts and prints all system calls a program makes).

```
strace bash -c '/usr/bin/ls > /dev/null; echo $?'
```

This gives the following output, much trimmed:

```
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/ls > /dev/null; echo $?"], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0
[....]
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ff16c3d69d0) = 1189
[....]
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 1189
[....]
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1189, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffd3096b290, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
[....]
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I used a bash script with two commands because otherwise bash doesn't fork but just execs the command, replacing itself (a useful optimization I just discovered it does!)

In the output, `clone` is the system call behind the `fork` function, and likewise `wait4` is called by `waitpid`. You don't see the `exec` because that happens in the child process, which we didn't ask `strace` to trace. If you add `-f` then it will do so, but will also trace the contents of the `ls` process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how the value gets passed between processes - is it passed via a register or is there a set memory location used?

Comment: When a process exits it calls `_exit(n)` (unless killed by a signal), and the kernel stores the exit code, `n`. The parent process can then retrieve the value using some variant of the `wait` system call.